# Ethernet connection keeps reconnecting on Manjaro Linux

Tags: networking, ethernet, manjaro, realtek

I am using `5.1.18-1-MANJARO` with KDE Plasma version `5.16.3`

Since last update using Octopi I am facing this issue of Ethernet reconnection.

```
sudo modprobe r8169
sudo modprobe r8168
```

I have tried running modprobe command but had no success
Tried running this command for installing drivers, still no improvements

```
sudo pacman -S linux41-r8169
error: target not found: linux41-r8169
```

Output of `lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
        Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
        Memory at a4310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Memory at a432a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
        Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at a432b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
        Memory at a432c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
        Memory at a4328000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Memory at a432f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
        Memory at a432d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
        Memory behind bridge: a3000000-a3ffffff [size=16M]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000a1ffffff [size=288M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
        Memory behind bridge: a4200000-a42fffff [size=1M]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: None
        Memory behind bridge: a4000000-a41fffff [size=2M]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PMC
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at a4324000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 131
        Memory at a4320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at a4300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at a432e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GP108M [GeForce MX150]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
        Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nouveau

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Co
        Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
        Memory at a4204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at a4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8168
        Kernel modules: r8169, r8168

03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
        Memory at a4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
        Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

P.S. : WiFi is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below:

1. Go to Start Menu and open "System Settings"
2. Scroll down to "Network > Connections", select "Wired connection" under "Wired Ethernet" and then go to "Wired" tab where you will find "Link negotiation"

Solution A: If it is set to "Ignore", change it to "Automatic"

Solution B: If it is set to "Automatic", change it to "Manual"